# Query to lookup reference tables on sum the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL, would like to have your suggestions on how to solve this problem,

I have the sales information by type

[image]

I want to sum the Prices of certain references by Type and based on the resulting sum, fetch the values from another table and populate in the Output Column.

```
Group   Type    100000  200000  300000
1       A       1       2       3
1       B       0       1       1
2       T       2       2       4
2       U       0       2       2
3       V       2       2       3
4       N       1       1       1
```

From the above table 2 we find the TYPE A and B belong to same group - Group 1. So in the first table, the query should sum Prices of the references belonging to the Group 1. If the sum is >100000 and <=200000 then based on the type the  corresponding value must be chosen.

Incase the sum of Prices based on group is less than 100000 or the type not found in Table 2 then it should take the values from the below table

```
[+------+----+---+
| Type | 1  | 2 |
+------+----+---+
| A    | 50 | 2 |
| B    | 60 | 5 |
| C    | 65 | 2 |
| D    | 65 | 3 |
| E    | 65 | 4 |
+------+----+---+][3]
```

Thus the final output for the above datasheet would be like below,

```
Order ID    Reference  Type   Price    Output
101         AAA         A     500000      3
101         AAB         B     100000      1     
101         ABC         C     20000      67
101         DCE         B     50000       1
101         BOD         D     200000     68 
101         ZYZ         E     200000     69 
102         AAA         A    20000       52
```

So for the first line, its TYPE A and Type A is present under Group 1 and in Group1 we also have Type 2. So for the same order ID 101 , the overall Sales of Type A and B is 650000 > 300000, therefore for Type A we chose the value 3 from the table 2. Since Type C is not present in Table 2, I went to Table 3 and added the two values and so on

Sorry for the long post. Hope my question is clear? Would like to have your expert opinion.

Thanks,
SS

Comment: A better idea might be to fix your data model

Answer (score 0):

Join all tables and make sure you do `LEFT JOIN` as we want to keep records from the first table even we don't have corresponding data in the second or third table.

For total count, give priority to the second table, use `case when` to verify in which range this `mrp` field is falling. If lies within a range pick count from the second table otherwise pick count from the third table.

```
SELECT 
    s.order_id,
    s.reference,
    s.`type`,
    s.mrp,
    @a:= IFNULL(g_total.Total, s.mrp) AS MRP_Total,     -- @a variable to use it in CASE WHEN clause
    CASE 
        WHEN @a > 100000 AND @a <= 200000 AND sg.`type` IS NOT NULL THEN sg.price_100000
        WHEN @a > 200000 AND @a <= 300000 AND sg.`type` IS NOT NULL THEN sg.price_200000
        WHEN @a > 300000 AND sg.`type` IS NOT NULL THEN sg.price_300000
        ELSE tp.price_1 + tp.price_2
    END Total
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN sales_group sg ON s.`type` = sg.`type`
LEFT JOIN type_prices tp ON s.`type` = tp.`type`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        s.order_id, sgg.`group`, SUM(mrp) as Total
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN sales_group sgg ON s.`type` = sgg.`type`
    GROUP BY s.order_id, sgg.`group`
    ) AS g_total                                                  -- Temp table to find total MRP, order and group wise
    ON s.order_id = g_total.order_id AND sg.`group` = g_total.`group`
ORDER BY s.order_id, s.`type`;
```

Output:

```
sales
---
| order_id | reference | type | mrp     | MRP_Total | Total | 
---------------------------------------------------------
| 101      | AAA       | A    | 500000  | 650000    | 3     | 
| 101      | DCE       | B    | 50000   | 650000    | 1     | 
| 101      | AAB       | B    | 100000  | 650000    | 1     | 
| 101      | ABC       | C    | 200000  | 200000    | 67    | 
| 101      | BOD       | D    | 200000  | 200000    | 68    | 
| 101      | ZYZ       | E    | 200000  | 200000    | 69    | 
| 102      | AAA       | A    | 20000   | 20000     | 52    |
```

Note: `sg.type IS NOT NULL` is added in `CASE WHEN` clause because if we don't have any mapping in the second table, we should move to `ELSE` part which refers to the third table.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But Want I to achieve is that for every record, the query should sum the MRP based on its order and Type in the total table and only when the total of the MRP goes beyond the 100000 the CASE statements should be used. Currenly, the query compares the MRP and group type for each line. However Want I want is that the query reads the first record, finds its TYpe A goes to table 2 find its type A is present, if present find the other Types in the group and sum all the records present in the input table based on the Types and then fetch the total from Either table2 or 3

Comment: Share your actual table structure with sample data and expected output. Bcz my answer is returning same output as given in your question. Share create code and insert statements, so we can understand how it should be.

Comment: I think, I'm getting what you are saying, it would be good if you can share more sample data which covers your scenarios like multiple records for same order and type.

Comment: For 1st Record, the TYPE is 'A' so the query should check in the second table if this type is present, if present find the other Types which falls under the same group. We see from Table 2 that TYPE A is present in Group 1 and Group 1 has Type B also init . So now the query should sum all the records in the table for the Same Order ID and has the Type A and B. Therefore for Order ID 101, the Sum of MRP for Type A and B is 650000. Since its value is greather than 300000 we take the value based on your CASE statement. Like wise all the records should be traversed by the Query

Comment: sorry for long explanations, but hope its detail. I think, the current sample data will be enough for this logic. Let me know what modification needs to be done in the initial answer you provided or if you need some clarification.

Comment: Yup it explains, so you should update your expected output part, that is contradictory than your explanation. Type A is okay what about type B, both are in same group. Do we have single row in output ? If separate what would be value for that.

Comment: @SS6101, updated my answer. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it works for you. :)